# Pasa Lista de Entidades en un WebService WCF

Tags: c#, webservice, entity-framework-6, wcf

el día de hoy se me presenta un error al consumir un servicio web wcf, el error es el siguiente:

> No se pudo invocar el servicio. Causas posibles: el servicio está sin conexión o inaccesible. la configuración del cliente no coincide con el proxy; el proxy existente no es válido. Consulte el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información. Para intentar la recuperación, inicie un nuevo proxy, restablezca la configuración predeterminada o actualice el servicio.
>
> Error al recibir la respuesta HTTP a http://localhost:50246/OperacionService.svc. Puede deberse a que el enlace del extremo de servicio no usa el protocolo HTTP. También puede deberse a que el servidor anula un contexto de solicitud HTTP (posiblemente por el cierre del servicio). Consulte los registros del servidor para obtener más información.
>
> Server stack trace: 
>          en System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>          en System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>          en System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>          en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>          en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>          en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>          en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>          en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>          en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>          en IOperacionService.Test()
>          en OperacionServiceClient.Test()
>
> Inner Exception:
>       Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de recepción.
>          en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>          en System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> Inner Exception:
>       No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.
>          en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>          en System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>          en System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
>
> Inner Exception:
>       Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
>          en System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>          en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

La entidad a retornar es una entidad autogenerada por EntityFramework 6.2

```
public partial class Proceso
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Proceso()
        {
            this.ClasificacionDocumento = new HashSet<ClasificacionDocumento>();
        }


        public int IDProceso { get; set; }


        public string Proceso { get; set; }


        public string CODHomologacion { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ClasificacionDocumento> ClasificacionDocumento { get; set; }
    }
```

y El servicio tiene la siguiente implementación

```
public List<Proceso> Test()
    {
        List<Proceso> ls = new List<Proceso>();
        Proceso tp = new Proceso();
        DBContext psg = new DBContext();
        tp = psg.Set<Proceso>().Find(0);

        ls.Add(tp);
        return ls;
    }
}
```

El servicio falla al momento de retorno del dato, los objetos se crean y se llenan de forma correcta, y la lista hasta antes del retorno e correcta y contiene un elemento.

Agradezco de su ayuda.

Comment: Hola, has revisado tanto el `InnerException` como el `StackTrace` de la excepción producida? Te recomiendo englobes tu contexto en un bloque `using` para cerrarlo y hacer un `Dispose` del mismo

Comment: Revisa el tema de herencias.

Comment: Ya hice varias pruebas y he creado objetos del tipo Proceso llenando los tres atríbutos IDProceso, Proceso y CODHomologacion y adicionandolos a una lista y estos pasan sin inconvenientes, al parecer el problema es cuando trato de pasar la entidad con el constructor y la virtual collección

Comment: Hola, puedes incluir la configuración del `web.config`tanto del servidor como del cliente? Puede que sea un problema en la configuración del mismo que no te permite enviar ni recibir grandes cantidades de datos. Te dejo un enlace de lo que creo te está pasando [Transferring large blobs of data with WCF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ryberry/2010/04/20/transferring-large-blobs-of-data-with-wcf/)

Comment: No es una buena practica devolver o serializar para respuesta de un Web Service o WebApi un objeto Entity de EntityFramework; es muy común ver en los ejemplos de Microsoft y otras web eso, pero son solo ejemplos, no se debe hacer de esa manera. Deberías de usar el concepto de DTO's (Data Transfer Objects, Modelos o Business Entities) para transferir datos. Adicional, veo que estas utilizando un DbContext sin la clausula Using(Objeto){}, para asegurarte que al final del proceso de datos la conexión se cierra y destruye. Espero te ayude. Suerte!!!

Comment: En mi caso la solucion fue implementar DTOS y no devolver el objeto del modelo con sus relaciones. Que vergüenza no haberme dado cuenta.